# MySql: Exclude User if they have a certain role

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

```
SELECT distinct u.id, u.identifier, u.display_name, u.modified_time, 
u.active, r.id, r.name
FROM user u
left join user_role_mapping urm on u.id = urm.user_id
left join role r on r.id = urm.role_id 
where r.id IS NULL or r.name NOT IN ("System");
```

I have this MySQL query that is supposed to get every user as long as they don't have a role of "System", which is working fine. However, the problem I'm facing is if a user has a role of "System" and another role, the user is still being returned. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should select the value for the user that are not in list of user as system

```
  select u.id, u.identifier, u.display_name, u.modified_time, 
  u.active, r.id, r.name
  FROM user u
  left join user_role_mapping urm on u.id = urm.user_id
  left join role r on r.id = urm.role_id 
  where u.id not in (

      select u.id
      FROM user u
      left join user_role_mapping urm on u.id = urm.user_id
      left join role r on r.id = urm.role_id 
      where  r.name = "System"
  )
```

Comment: the join with user in the subquery is not needed, urm.user_id is good enough :-)

Comment: Yep just had to wait the 5 minutes.

Comment: absolutely, since the where-condition looks on role, you could also keep away the left(in the join), and since the join-criteria is u.id = urm.user_id ...

Comment: @turo  I have not the OP  schema of the table and looking to the join condition seem to me that all the condtion are need ..